# Atom / Rails: Why is Atom not showing the 'tmp' folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-editor

Just wanted to have a look into the 'tmp' folder of my Rails app.
It's there (i see it in the console), but it doesn't show up in Atom.

Why?

Comment: This is a question about programming specific software and is thus on topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmp` folder is probably ignored in git or other VCS you are using. Open settings tab in atom and check whether `Exclude VCS ignored path` is enabled and uncheck it if you want to display ignored files in the editor tree. Reload atom window (`View -> Developer -> Reload Window`) after updating settings if needed

Answer (score 1):

Incase if someone still has issues viewing gitignored files & if the accepted answer doesn't work.

```
- Navigate to: Atom -> Preferences -> Packages -> "Search for 'tree-view'"
- Click on tree-view package and click on settings
- Uncheck "Hide VCS Ignored Files"
```

The Files should be visible now.

[Source](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-1-5-3-not-showing-tmp-folder/25591/2)